# validar una dirección de correo electrónico sin expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, html, validación

```js
function validarCorreo(elemento){
      var correo = document.getElementById('email').value;
      arroba = correo.indexOf("@");
      punto =  correo.lastIndexOf(".");
      if (arroba < 1 || ( punto - arroba < 2 )||correo===""){
         alert("correo invalido");
      }else{
          alert("correo valido");
        }
 }
```

```html
 <p class="email">
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Email*" id="email" name="email" onblur="validarCorreo(this)">
    </p>
```

Estoy tratando de hacer una validación de correo electrónico sin usar expresiones regulares hasta ahora este código funciona pero me permite ingresar una extension cualquiera es decir me permite hacer esto:`hola23@gmail.comoestas`, como pueden ver la extension puede ser cualquiera entonces mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer que solo me acepte una extension con un máximo de 3 caracteres.

Comment: Y si usas un campo `<input type="email">`?

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero  ya encontré la solución

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podría servir:

```js
const mailOne = 'foo@bar.com'
const mailTwo = 'foo@bar.comx'

const listMailOne = mailOne.split(".")
const listMailTwo = mailTwo.split(".")

console.log(mailOne + " is:", listMailOne.pop().length < 4)
console.log(mailTwo + " is:", listMailTwo.pop().length < 4)
```

Comment: gracias justo lo que buscaba

Comment: Si usas **@foo.com** da como resultado true, [lo cual es incorrecto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax).

Comment: se supone que es la validación de la extensión, por lo que él está preguntando y tendrá que añadirla luego de la implementación que indica.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza Split para separar por un delimitador , en este caso seria el punto el delimitador y luego verificas el tamaño de la extensión

```js
function validarCorreo(elemento){
      var correo = document.getElementById('email').value;
      arroba = correo.indexOf("@");
      punto =  correo.lastIndexOf(".");
      extension= correo.split(".")[1];
      
      if (arroba < 1 || ( punto - arroba < 2 )||correo===""){
         alert("correo invalido");
      }else{
        if(extension.length >3){
          alert("correo invalido");
          return;
        }
        alert("correo valido");
      }
 }
```

```html
 <p class="email">
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Email*" id="email" name="email" onblur="validarCorreo(this)">
    </p>
```

Comment: fallará para los correos tipo: foo.x@bar.com

Comment: si fallaría si el correo tiene punto adelante del arroba .. pero mi respuesta fue basado en lo que la persona pregunto , como ver la extensión si tiene mas de 3 caracteres .. y para sacar la extensión se ´puede usar split.. De ahí la función que esta haciendo el compañero en realidad va fallar en muchos casos, y no entiendo por que no quiere usar expresiones regulares, pero si no debe usar expresiones regulares otra forma es usar HTML5 y utilizar el mismo control de email que ya viene.